# What is the equivalent of piezoelectricity for optics/photonics?

Tags: optics, piezoelectric

Piezoelectricity can be considered as the electromechanical transduction behaviour, where a material can convert mechanical deformation/energy directly to voltage difference / electricity or vice versa. Are there any materials which have the same behaviour but for optics/photonics? For example when they are under pressure emit photons, or deform when they absorb photons. What would this type of materials should be called?

Answer (score 2):

Photons don't interact the same way with matter as electrons in a crystal lattice. It's the rearrangement of electrons that causes the material to deform. Photon's on the other hand are packets of energy that are said to be mass-less while they travel through space and are converted or release their energy when they collide with matter. see Crookes radiometer. The movement of the vanes only occurs while there is some gas present (partial vacuum). If photons had mass that was causing the movement of the vanes then they (the vanes) would continue to move right through to a deep vacuum. To date I know of no material that emits light under pressure.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. But how about [Bioluminescent bacteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioluminescent_bacteria) for example?!

Comment: The light is due to a chemical reaction where light is given off by the transference of electrons and not the deformation of the chemicals which would give off light once mixed regardless of the pressure placed on them. Squeezing the poor little bacteria doesn't count but I see your point.

Comment: What if we use LASER? There is nothing for that either?!

Comment: To my knowledge there is no material that when deformed produces photon emissions. By its definition LASER "Light Amplification by Stimulated Emission of Radiation" does not meet the criteria of your question.